# if else?? try?? I need help on methods

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

If one method work and other doesn't then how do I make the code try a alternative method?

Here is the code

**1st method**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail")).click();
```

**2nd method**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
```

If the first method doesn't work I want it to go ahead and try the second method but, I don't know what command to use for this.

I am not very experienced at programming so please bear with me.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Please be more specific.

Comment: lets say I want it to click "insert element#1 here", but if it doesn't click that element, how do I make it click an alternative "insert element#2 here"?

Comment: What do you mean by *"if it doesn't click that element"*? The element wasn't found? The click failed? Something else?

Comment: Instead capturing the NullPointerException if findElement returns null, you should split the call to a temporal variable and see is findElement returned null. If it doesn't, then call click, if it does, then repeat with the second method. Don't use exceptions if you can do it cleanly.

Comment: @LuisGP - `findElement` throws when the element isn't found, rather than returning `null`. But they could do that with `findElements`. I updated my answer to show how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try catch block for this purpose :

```
try {

  driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail")).click();             
  driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail")).click();
catch (Exception e) {
  driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click(); 
  driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
}
```

you can give a specific exception too, for example "ElementNotFoundException" or "ElementNotVisibleException" in your catch parameter type

Comment: [The documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) only indicates `findElement` throws `NoSuchElementException`, not `ElementNotFoundException` or `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you should be aware of other method's exceptions too for example .click() method raises ElementNotVisibleException and StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: True, it depends on what the OP means by "doesn't work."

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "doesn't work" you mean the element wasn't found. Two options:

1. According to [the documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-), `findElement` raises a `NoSuchElementException` if the element isn't found. So you can continue to use `findElement` and catch the exception via `try`/`catch`.
2. Alternately, use [`findElements`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-), which returns a `List`, and branch based on whether any were found. As [LuisGP pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839917/if-else-try-i-need-help-on-methods/54840002#comment96453639_54839917), avoiding exceptions is often helpful.

**Option 1:**

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail")).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
}
```

Or if you meant to handle those one-by-one:

```
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail")).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click(); 
}
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail")).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
}
```

**Option 2** (if you want to handle them one-by-one, you should be able to tweak if you want to branch on just the first result):

```
List<WebElement> elements;
elements = driver.findElements(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail"));
if (element.size() == 0) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle")).click(); 
} else {
    elements.get(0).click();
}
elements = driver.findElements(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail"));
if (elements.size() == 0) {
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done")).click();
} else {
    elements.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: Dear @T.J. Crowder thanks for sharing your time to help SO community.

Answer (score 0):

You can try click on an element out of 4 given elements which is visible and clickable. It will make you to safe to clicking on element after catching exception and good practice to follow. It will throw exception only when no element will be found out of 4 and it is valid case.

```
MobileElement A = driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/dir_thumbnail"));
MobileElement B = driver.findElement(By.id("com.simplemobiletools.gallery:id/medium_thumbnail"));
MobileElement C = driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/circle"));
MobileElement D = driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/done"));

public void clickOnElement() {
    try {
        if(A.isDisplayed() && A.isEnabled())
        {
            A.click();
        }
        if(B.isDisplayed() && B.isEnabled())
        {
            B.click();
        }
        if(C.isDisplayed() && C.isEnabled())
        {
            C.click();
        }
        if(D.isDisplayed() && D.isEnabled())
        {
            D.click();
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Just call 'clickOnElement' method in your test case.